# How to do a fixup commit of a fixup commit and autosquash it?

Tags: git

### Scenario

I have a repository with its own `master` branch.

```
* abcdef012 2023-09-24 somebody (HEAD -> master, origin/master) some commit
```

My collegue (called `dev1`), opens a feature branch.

```
* 012345678 2023-09-25 dev1     (origin/feat/dev1) first feat commit
* abcdef012 2023-09-24 somebody (HEAD -> master, origin/master) some commit
```

I open a fix branch to improve `feat` branch and I create a *fixup commit*.

```
* 000000000 2023-09-26 me       (HEAD -> fix/dev1) fixup! first feat commit
* 012345678 2023-09-25 dev1     (feat/dev1, origin/feat/dev1) first feat commit
* abcdef012 2023-09-24 somebody (master, origin/master) some commit
```

### Problem

Now I realize I need to *fixup* my *fixup commit*; at the end of my job I want to deliver a *clean branch* with just one fixup commit.

So I try doing a *fixup commit* of my previous *fixup commit* (as I do for other commits)...

`git commit --fixup=000000000`

```
* 111111111 2023-09-26 me       (HEAD -> fix/dev1) fixup! fixup! first feat commit
* 000000000 2023-09-26 me       fixup! first feat commit
* 012345678 2023-09-25 dev1     (feat/dev1, origin/feat/dev1) first feat commit
* abcdef012 2023-09-24 somebody (master, origin/master) some commit
```

... and I try to *autosquash* it...

`git rebase --autosquash feat/dev1`

... expecting following result...

```
* 222222222 2023-09-26 me       (HEAD -> fix/dev1) fixup! first feat commit
* 012345678 2023-09-25 dev1     (feat/dev1, origin/feat/dev1) first feat commit
* abcdef012 2023-09-24 somebody (master, origin/master) some commit
```

while instead the `git rebase --autosquash feat/dev1` command leaves the commit tree untouched (i.e. as after the `git commit --fixup=000000000` command). :(

### Question

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible to be done with *fixup/autosquash* git feature?

I know there are many many long routes to achieve tha same goal; what I'm looking for is a way to do it through just two command lines as I usually do to *fixup* my **non** *fixup* commits: the two previously said commands.

Comment: IIRC, there is special handling that recognizes that fixup! fixup! commits are actually directed to a commit that the earlier fixup! commit wants to fix up. It would imagine that if said earlier fixup! commit does not find the commit it wants to fix up (it does not find it in your case because you rebase not far enough back in the history), then the fixup chain is broken and nothing gets fixed up.

Comment: Thank you @j6t ; unfortunately this explains why I don't get my expected behavior but doesn't answer to the question: which command have I to issue rather than `git commit --fixup=000000000` to produce a commit which will be squashed by next rebase command?

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems:

Firstly, `git rebase --autosquash feat/dev1` will ignore `--autosquash`. You must request an interactive rebase operation:

```
git rebase -i --autosquash feat/dev1
```

Secondly, there is special handling that recognizes that a double "fixup! fixup!" commit is actually directed to a commit that an earlier regular "fixup!" commit wants to fix up. For this to work, the commit to fix up must also be among the rebased commits. However, in your case it is not because you rebase not far enough back in the history. In this case, the fixup chain is broken and no fix-ups are recorded.

You must request the fixup manually by changing the second `pick` command in the todo-sheet to `fixup`.

Comment: Sorry, could you please elaborate a bit more "You must request the fixup manually by changing the second `pick` command in the todo-sheet to `fixup`"? Thank you

Comment: Did you try the command? Have you been presented an editor with a (so called) todo-sheet with two lines beginning with `pick`? That is where you should change the `pick` on the second line to `fixup`. There's explanation near the end of the todo-sheet. And there's the [manual page about interactive rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_interactive_mode).

Comment: No, I never tried `rebase -i`. Now I have clear why I wasn't able to understand your answer. Thank you for the doc, I'll read it carefully to better understand your answer.